# How does Android Studio's Generate Signed APK translate into command line statements?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradlew

When I do the following, I get a compiled and signed apk:

- Select Build -> Generate Signed Bundle or APK
- Select APK
- Select my jks file and give the correct passwords etc
- Select Build variant *release*

Now I want to do the same on the command line (for use in a CI pipeline). I can see from the above output that it is *Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]*

When I open a terminal and type

```
gradlew :app:assembleRelease
```

I get the error

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_311 contains a valid JDK installation.

I cannot find tools.jar anywhere on my computer.

So the question is: What exactly is the wizard executing when compiling and signing the apk?

Comment: This is complaining about something being wrong with the Java you're using. 
Set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to point to Android Studio's included JRE at `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre` and you should have more success...